# Angular 17, Is Exist Library Like Cell-Curser In Angular JS

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I want to implement in angular the drag of cells like Excel

I want to implement in angular the drag of cells like Excel
in AngularJs there is Library call cell-curser, but I need it in angular, to drag one column to another columns in table, and paste the data to the dragged columns

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!